# VIEWS: How can i Related (CONCATENATE) current_user to content fields?

Tags: views

DRUPAL ROCKS!

I need your help! in a website i am currently working with. i have 700 active users with the following users field:
-Name, Sure name, last name, worker number.

And i created a content type called: Turns.With the fields: title, body, full name, turn's date, worker number.

One of the main goals of this website is that in the moment that the user logs in he will have a button that say my turns, and he will just see his "turns".

i need to be able to related in a view, some how, user's worker number with turns (content, node) worker number field in order to show just user "turns".

view=user(work number field) + turns(work number field) and off course display all the turn fields.

any help will be really really appreciated...

love drupal!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Relation (on the right side), Here you can link to a author. Create a filter that filters on the current loged in user. This should do the trick.